# java access modifier- visibility of attributes whose type is other class. why it is visible or not?

Tags: java, modifier

below are some nesty example of java access modifiers. I can't clearly figure out answers when classes have attributes whose type is other classes.

```
package packageX;
import packageY.*;

public class A {
    public int x;
    private int y;
    protected int z;

    public A objA;
    public C objC;

    void test(){
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
        System.out.println(z);

        System.out.println(objA.x);
        System.out.println(objA.y);
        System.out.println(objA.z);

        System.out.println(objC.x);
        System.out.println(objC.y);//not visible
        System.out.println(objC.z);//?? why visible?
    }
}

class B{
    public A objA;
    public C objC;

    void test(){
        System.out.println(x);//not visible
        System.out.println(y);//not visible
        System.out.println(z);//not visible

        System.out.println(objA.x);
        System.out.println(objA.y);//not visible
        System.out.println(objA.z);

        System.out.println(objC.x);
        System.out.println(objC.y);//not visible
        System.out.println(objC.z);//?? why visible?
    }
}



package packageY;
import packageX.*;

public class C extends A{
    public A objA;
    public C objC;

    void test(){
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);//not visible
        System.out.println(z);

        System.out.println(objA.x);
        System.out.println(objA.y);//not visible
        System.out.println(objA.z);//not visible//??? why not visible?

        System.out.println(objC.x);
        System.out.println(objC.y);//not visible//??? why visible?
        System.out.println(objC.z);
    }

}

class D{
    public A objA;
    public C objC;

    void test(){
        System.out.println(x);//not visible
        System.out.println(y);//not visible
        System.out.println(z);//not visible

        System.out.println(objA.x);
        System.out.println(objA.y);//not visible
        System.out.println(objA.z);//not visible

        System.out.println(objC.x);
        System.out.println(objC.y);//not visible
        System.out.println(objC.z);//not visible//??? why not visible
    }
}
```

I can't understand few lines with //??? can you expain why the attributes are visible or not?

Comment: Please post all the relevant code as text rather than an image.

Comment: Please also post all relevant classes (i.e : `A`)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a time to read some basic docs?

`private int a` - visible only in this class

`protected int a` - visible in this class and in all children classes extending this class

`int a` - visible from all classes in the same package as this class

`public int a` - visible from any other classes

Comment: how about objA.z in class C. As C is subclass of A objA.z(protected) in C should be visible but it is not

Comment: ObjA is not objC, only z belonging to objC is visible inside objC. Not from other objA. If you need it use either `public` or if classes are in the same package - package visibility with no modifier.

Answer (score 0):

This will explain Access https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

`y` is not visible in `C` because `C` extends `A` and `A` has made `y` private.  Therefore `C` cannot see `y`.

`z` is protected so sub classes can see `z`.

Class B cannot see any of those variables because it does not inherit from any other class and it does not define those variables.

In class B `objA.y` can not be access because y is private.  You can not access a private variable from outside the class that declares it.

`objC.z` is visible because protected members can be access by sub classes.

Read the link I provided.  It explains this in the first table.

Comment: Yeah I know the case of x,y,z. What I wonder is the case of objA and objC. For example objC.z is visible in class A, but as I know C is defined in other package with A so objC.z(protected-> should be seen in same package and its subclasses) should be not visible in A

Comment: but isn't A is super class of C?

Comment: ObjC.z is inherited from A.  z belongs to a.  It is protected so it can be accessed by an instance of C.  An instance of C can be created by any class and they can access z.  Even if the super class creates an instance of the subclass..

Comment: Thank! Then could you tell me why objA.y, objA.z is not visible in class C?? According to your comments, a instance of class A can access x, y and z(objA.x, objA.y, objA.z) however it's not in class C.

Comment: D is not in the same package as A therefore protected members like Z are not accessible.  Please read the link I provided it explains all of this with a simple example.